# How to construct a five-branch tree with depth over 100 in python?

Tags: tree

Dear fellows in the community, currently I'm trying to approximate the value of a bond using tree structure. My clue is to construct a tree with 5 child on each node with over 100 depth, then using backward induction to approximate the value of the 1st parent value, using a certain function. The ideal tree structure is ideally:

[Except there're 5 child nodes at each point:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0Fs.png)

*My major concern is related to computing power. When I did similar computation on excel VBA, my computer can only handle up to the 11th depth. What will you recommend to use to achieve this goal using tree or other methods? Plus, what method will you recommend to set up the basic 100-depth empty framework? Thanks!*

Thanks for the blunt comments down here, >100 depth is kinda a requirement I can't alter so instead of cutting the depth I'll see if there's anyway to simplify my algorithm and eliminate some nodes.

Thanks for the comments, pals!

Comment: How many nodes do you expect this tree to contain? Why? How much memory do you expect should be necessary in order to store the tree data? Why? Also, why is this tagged as a `python` question? And why would creating a tree like this help you solve the problem? What do trees have to do with bond values? Why should there be 5 children at each node, and why should the depth be large?

Comment: Try to calculate `5**100` does this seem to be a reasonable number to handle?

Comment: You edited your question without addressing most of the comments. I'll make it short and explicit. What you want to do is impossible.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the feedback! Then how does like 10^10 or 10^20 sound like for backward induction sound like? :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your reply! I am trying to stimulate potential bond value changes in 100+ time periods to discover its value so the depth is the time periods covered and childs denotes potential value change directions. :)

Comment: `10**10` is a number a computer can handle in terms of storage. Now in terms of complexity/computation, it depends on the specifics (which you have not provided). You should read how to ask a good SO question. Provide a minimal and reproducible example with the input and expected output. Provide minimal code or the algorithm you want to use (not a name, the actual implementation). Regarding the context (bonds or else), it might help understanding but this is really not critical.

Comment: I don't think you really understand the comments. Still your question goes on *"...>100 depth is kinda a requirement I can't alter"*. With a branching factor of 5 you are thus saying, *"I have a requirement to do the impossible"*. So what do you expect? It is likely that you are searching in the wrong direction, but since you have not explained anything about how a tree is going to help you to approximate some value, we cannot help you, other than repeating it is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraints of physics, it is simply impossible to maintain a tree with that many nodes. At a depth of 100, you'd end up with over 10^69 nodes, which is approaching orders of magnitude near the number of atoms in the universe (10^80).

You may want to reconsider how you are going to perform your calculations. Even if you didn't generate the entire tree, the amount of processing power it would take to iterate over all the nodes would simply unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

There are three factors that strike me in this question.

**The first factor**, which is correctly picked up by many of the comments and also answered by @Miguel. The algo would simply end up with far to many nodes. This is a limit in itself.

**Secondly**, which is yet to be pointed out, if one was to take this approach to model a bond, then they would be using a binary or binomeal tree and the reason for this is that at any point in time there are only `two` outcomes. [1] a payment (`True`), [2] a non payment (`False`).

**Thirdly**, the model approach would be improved in time be reducing the depth (which does reduce accuracy).

The second and third points that are made in this answer ***significantly*** reduce the computing power.